# function prototype declaration fails compilation

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to `c`. I am trying to read through Holub's `Compiler Design In C`. In a file called `set.c` in Appendix A of the book, the author uses a `function prototype` declaration as shown below.

```
extern int      _addset     P((SET* , int ));
```

This fails during compilation for me. The error is listed below. I am using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`.

```
include/tools/set.h:25:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘P’
 extern void     delset              P((SET* ));
```

When I changed the declaration as shown below, the code compiles.

```
extern int      _addset(SET* , int );
```

As I am not too well versed with `c`, I am not certain if I am doing something wrong by changing the code like this. Could anybody tell me if the above syntax is valid and why doesn't the syntax from the book compile ? Holub does stress on the importance of using ANSI C, but based on what I read GCC is ANSI (or more properly ISO) compliant.

Comment: It looks like it's depending on a macro definition for `P` that isn't present when you tried to compile it.  Are you missing some include?  Does the book give the definition of `P`?

Comment: There are no includes on top of the header file. The author is usually comprehensive with his code. So I assumed the `P` is just a place holder which doesn't have any meaning. 

[Compiler Design In C](http://www.holub.com/software/compilerDesignInC.pdf)

I am only linking the book in case you are interested. It is by no means a suggestion to look at the code to help me. Although, that would be nice. The `set.h` is on page 696.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `P` preprocessor macro.  The Compiler Design in C book is old, so the author has provided a workaround for similarly old (now ancient) compilers regarding argument lists.  The book describes what it's for:

> The P macro on lines 25 and 28 handles another ANSI-related
>   portability problem.  Many compilers (including many UNIX compilers)
>   can't handle function prototypes.     This macro uses a mechanism similar
>   to the D () macro discussed earlier to translate prototypes   into
>   simple extern declarations if ANSI is not defined. For example, given
>   the   following input:
>
> ```
>   int dimitri P(( int x, long y ));
> ```
>
> if ANSI is defined, the P (x) macro evaluates to its argument and the
>   following translation results:
>
> ```
>   int dimitri ( int x, long y );
> ```
>
> otherwise, the macro discards its argument and evaluates to () , so
>   the following will be     created:
>
> int dimitri ();

The idea being that if you have an ANSI-compliant compiler, you're supposed to `#define ANSI` before including the header file that defines `P`.  Then `P` leaves your argument list alone.  But if you don't have an ANSI-compliant compiler, you don't define `ANSI` and the preprocessor removes your argument list.  `P` looks like this:

```
#ifdef ANSI
#define P(x) x
#else
#define P(x) ()
#endif
```

I recommend removing `P` altogether, like you did.  However, you can also `#define ANSI` or `#define P(x) x` if you want to be able to copy-and-paste code from the book as-is.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the comma after SET *

It shouldn't be there.

Comment: I removed the comma and compiled it. It still fails. Besides, that method takes in two arguments, that comma separates the two, no ? The declaration should be more like this.

`_addset(SET* a, int b);`

But parameter identifiers are optional in `Function Prototype` declaration. Therefore the method only shows types separated by comma.