# What is the function of Macro definition "__P" in getopt_long.c

Tags: c

As stated in the title, the source code site:[libevent/WIN32-Code/getopt_long.c](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/WIN32-Code/getopt_long.c):

```
#define __P(x) x
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36297919/634919

Comment: Symbols beginning with double underscore are reserved for "the implementation" (i.e. the compiler and the library). So it's an internal implementation-specific macro which really isn't relevant to others than the people working on the library.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ugh. ANSI C is the worst sometimes.

Comment: In this case it seems that this macro is a remnant from the "olden" days, in the transition-period from K&R C function declarations and ANSI function declarations.